# Scala sequence, each element represents sum of all previous elements

Tags: scala, collections, sequence

I have a sequence collection in Scala as follows:

```
val DaysInMonths = Seq(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)
```

How efficiently I can convert this sequence into such sequence where each element represents sum of previous elements like below:

```
  val DaysInMonths = Seq(31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365)
```

I have one working solution below:

```
DaysInMonths.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(Seq.empty[Int]) {
  case (Nil, (cur, _)) => Seq(cur)
  case (acc, (cur, 1)) if isLeapYear(year) => acc ++ Seq(acc.last + 29)
  case (acc, (cur, i)) => acc ++ Seq(acc.last + cur)
}
```

But as I am new to Scala and I am wondering that there should be better & shorter way to achieve the same.

Comment: The "solution" seems to be a solution to a bit more general (and difficult) problem, than what you state in your question. In which of them are you interested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scanLeft`:

```
scala>   DaysInMonths.scanLeft(0)(_ + _)
res1: Seq[Int] = List(0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365)
```

Note that it adds the initial value to the sequence, you can decide if you want to keep it or take the tail and ignore it.

Comment: So I think final solution can be:  `DaysInMonths.scanLeft(0)(_ + _).tail`

Comment: close, you have to trim the head: `scanLeft(0)(_ + _).tail`